# Extract fields from JsArray in scala on play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a JSArray like below from server (I cannot change as it belongs to others):

```
[ {"name": "US", "id": 0, "translations" : {"name: {"es": "Estados unidos", "fr": "Etats-unis"}}},
{"name": "UK", "id": 1, "translations" : {"name: {"es": "Estados Kdda", "fr": "dsfjas"}}},
...
]
```

I need to extract all the name like US, UK but not name in `translations` and also id.

I tried several ways and it always have problem. Below are what I tried.

I first tried

```
case class Country(name: String, id:String) 

implicit object CountryReads extends Reads[Country] {  
def reads(json: JsValue) = Country(
                        (json \ "name"),
                        (json \ "id")
                    )
}

val countries = Json.parse(result) match {  //here result is Json String
           case JsArray(Seq(t)) => Some(t.as[Seq[Country]])
           case _ => None
}
```

But I get compiling error as below:

```
[error] C:\git9\hss\app\models\LivingSocial.scala:80: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[MyCountry]
[error]                        def reads(json: JsValue) =    (json \ "currencyCode")
[error]                                                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

then I tried:

```
val jResult = Json.parse(result)
(jResult \\ "name").foreach { name => 
   println(name.as[String])
}
```

I get error in `println()` as "\" will recursively pull names under translation also.

Any good way to do it?

Comment: Your compiler error references a `currencyCode` field which isn't in your code.  Are you sure that's everything?

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Country(name: String, id: Int, translations: Map[String, Map[String, String]])

object Country {

  implicit val format = Json.format[Country]

}

val js = Json.parse(yourString)

val names: JsResult[Seq[String]] = js.validate[Seq[Country]].map { countries => countries.map(_.name) }
```

At that point you can deal with the `JsResult` since you'll need error handling in case the JSON doesn't conform to your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your read to look like this :

```
implicit val CountryReads: Reads[Country] = (
        (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
          (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
        )(Country.apply _)
```

this is a correct way to create a reader according to play documentation

Comment: There is no one right way to create a reader according to the pre-canned `Reads` definitions in the play source - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala